# How to access Linux Global variables using Java program

Tags: java, linux

Thank you all for you assistance,

I have shell script program which export value. Here is my shell script program

```
#! /bin/sh
export TEST=35
echo "echo $TEST"
```

I have executed the shell script using the command ./test.sh as well as source ./test.sh
(test.sh - shell script program name)
I have tried to print the value in command prompt to make sure that TEST variable to export-ed and it prints TEST value as 35. Test variable is exported as expected.

Now i have piece of java which access this TEST - linux global variable. sample code as follows,

```
import java.util.Map;

public class hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            System.out.println(System.getProperty("TEST"));
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Now the issue is when i execute the java program i am getting the TEST value as null. 
Now My question is am i doing a write way to access the GLobal variable from java. if not how can i access the Linux Global variable from java program.

Comment: These are called *environment variables*, not “global variables”.  Java's system properties are yet an additional concept which is why your lookup doesn't return the expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.getenv` api like below

```
 String test = System.getenv().get("TEST")
```

[getenv](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29) will return you a map from which you can fetch your variable. On the other hand, [getProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) method is used to  get System properties that say while starting the jvm you supplied using -DMyVar=Value.

Make sure you define variable at parent shell and not as sub shell or else launch jvm from your script itself to access the variable using getenv as if you launch your jvm from parent shell then your variable exported in subshell wont be available to parent shell.

Comment: Thank you, i am getting the below error message, getenv(java.lang.String) in java.lang.System cannot be applied to ()

Comment: You are welcome. Dont forget to close this question by accepting the answer so it could help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

In small project it is enough to use

```
System.getenv().get("variable_name");
```

If your project use/will use maven then you should write in your pom.xml

```
${env.variable_name}
```